# ¿Cómo crear un objeto o array asociativo dinámico en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy recorriendo el body de una tabla [html](/questions/tagged/html) y deseo capturar la posición del (**td**) donde los **selects** están seleccionados, esto ocurre en un evento  **click** [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).
Tengo lo siguiente:

```
                //creo el objeto
                 var objetoSelects = new Object();
                 $('#vistaPre tbody tr').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).find("td").each(function(i, el) {
                        // .selectOptions son selects que tengo en un td de la tabla
                        $('.selectOptions').find(':selected').each(function(j, el) {
                            $this = $(this).val();
                            if ($this != '') {

                             // intento crear las posiciones del objeto

                             objetoSelects.$this = j;

                             objetoSelects.selects = $this;

                            }

                        });
                        // salgo del each
                        return false;
                    });
                    // salgo del each
                    return false;
                });
```

Mi intención es crear un objeto de esta manera:

```
// $this es el valor del select ejemplo ('item1')
// j es el contador en este caso la posición actual del <td>
// selects es el valor que le deseo dar a mi otro dato (creo que no esta bien)
objetoSelects(itemx = x, 'selects' = itemx);
```

No encuentro la manera de hacerlo.

**UPDATE**

Tomando en cuenta las respuestas, encontré una manera de hacerlo, *a continuación dejo la manera en que resolví el problema*

```
                // cree arrays para guardar la posición del <td> y el valor del select
                var arraySelects  = [];
                var arrayPosition = [];

                $('#vistaPre tbody tr').each(function (index2) {
                    $(this).find("td").each(function(i, el) {
                        //
                        $('.selectOptions').find(':selected').each(function(j, el) {
                            $this = $(this).val();
                            if ($this != '') {

                                //agrego los datos correspondientes
                                arrayPosition.push(j);
                                arraySelects.push($this);

                            }

                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                    return false;
                });
                // creo el objeto y le asigno los valores
                var datoSelect = { 'position': arrayPosition, 'selects': arraySelects};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alan, te dejo aqui un ejemplo de lo que estas buscando. Script JS nátivo sin Librerias externas.

```js
//Aqui buscamos todos los TR de la tabla
var a = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
var arreglo = [];
if(a != undefined || a!= null){
  for(var b in a){ //Como que Query Selector All nos entrega un array, entonces ieramos
    var c = a[b];
    if(typeof c == "object"){ //Solo ocupamos los objetos 
      var check = c.querySelector("td input[type='checkbox']:checked"); //ahora que tenemos los tr entonces buscamos dentro de ellos los checkbox que esten checked
      if(check.checked){ //Si estan checked entonces...
        //aqui agrega tu array como necesites
        arreglo.push({"fila":c.rowIndex,"celda":check.parentNode.cellIndex});
        
      //console.log("Fila: "+c.rowIndex,"celda: "+check.parentNode.cellIndex);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(arreglo);
```

```html
<!--Te dejo un tabla para que puedas ejecutar el script, solo modifica a tus necesidades.-->
<table border="">
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a" checked="checked" /><label for="a">opcion</label></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="b" name="b" /><label for="b">opcion</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="c" name="c" /><label for="c">opcion</label></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="d" name="d" checked="checked" /><label for="d">opcion</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="e" name="e" checked="checked" /><label for="e">opcion</label></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="f" name="f" /><label for="f">opcion</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta.

```
 var arraySelects = new Object();
```

creas un objecto pero por el nombre supongo que quieres un array?

si definitivamente si quieres un objeto entonces puedes hacer:

```
arraySelects['clave'] = valor;
```

recordermos que `arraySelects` lo creaste como un objeto, luego de terminar ese llamado, puedes consultar `arraySelects['key']` remplazando `key` por el nombre que le diste cuando lo estabas guardando.

Comment: Vaya que estaba confundido, inicialmente era un array, pero despues de investigar me di cuenta que en [tag:javascript] a los array asociativos se les llama objetos segun lo documentan [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos), muchas gracias por la ayuda voy a probar lo que me dices

Answer (score 1):

Puedes asignar valores directamente usando la sintaxis para crear objetos:

`objetoSelects = {"items": x, "select": itemx}`